# Jquery, Colorbox Issue, Colorbox content opening twice in second click

Tags: jquery, delegates, colorbox

I'm having a problem using jquery and the colorbox lightbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) plugin.

The content being loaded into the colorbox duplicates if you open it more than once from the same link. Two iframes are being created in the colorbox.

I'm using delegate to bind the colorbox function to the anchor link - I don't get this issue if I bind colorbox in the standard fashion - I'd like to be binding in the standard fashion but this part of my page can be reloaded by the user (jquery load) so this is not possible.

I've setup a live example at: http://213.171.220.77/

You'll notice that the second time you click on the 'MORE INFO' link two versions of the Iframe appear in the colorbox.

Press ESC to exit the colorbox.

Regards

S

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.
You need to call the colorbox, let's say 'directly'.
First of all, remove the 'open: true' setting.
Then add instead the href setting 'href: this.href'.
As a third I suggest 'transition: elastic' to avoid some 'flickering' after click.

Comment: Can you paste a little code snippet on your answer? just to be more clearer, thanks.